# Codename One: Setting Timeline as background image

Tags: java, image, codenameone

I want to add an animated image or video to my splash screen. It should fit the screen size for different devices. At first i tried to add an .mp4 , which worked, but I could not get the transitions right (showed black rectangle before going to the next form). So I changed to a timeline, added the gif to the .res file and tried to draw it. Nothing of what I tried worked out, I am running out of options so I thought I would ask if there is a better way.

**Option 1: Set BG**

```
protected void beforeVideoSplash(Form f) {
    super.beforeVideoSplash(f);
    FormFactory.modifyBaseForm(f);

    Timeline splashGif = null;

    try {
        splashGif = (Timeline) Resources.openLayered("/theme").getImage("vNewSplash480x360.gif");
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    f.getAllStyles().setBgImage(splashGif);

}
```

Result: Simulator shows white screen. Crashes on android device (Tablet and phone).

**Option 2: Paint on glass pane**

```
protected void beforeVideoSplash(Form f) {
    super.beforeVideoSplash(f);
    FormFactory.modifyBaseForm(f);

    f.setGlassPane( new Painter() {

        public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle rect) {
            Timeline splashGif = null;

            try {
                splashGif = (Timeline) Resources.openLayered("/theme").getImage("vNewSplash480x360.gif");
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            splashGif.requiresDrawImage();

            Display display = Display.getInstance();

            int imgWidth = display.getDisplayWidth();
            int imageHeight = 320 * display.getDisplayWidth() / 480;

            g.drawImage(splashGif, 0, (display.getDisplayHeight() - imageHeight) / 2, imgWidth, imageHeight); 
        }
    }
    );

}
```

Result: White screen on simulator and android devices.

**Option 3: Scaled**

Not to repeat myself, I scaled the image like so:

```
    Image scaled;

    Display display = Display.getInstance();

    if (display.getDisplayWidth() > display.getDisplayHeight()) {
        scaled = splashGif.scaledWidth(display.getDisplayHeight());
    } else {
        scaled = splashGif.scaledWidth(display.getDisplayWidth());
    }
```

And then added it to a Label inside a Container with BorderLayout with a CENTER constraint.

Result: This way actually worked, but app ran too slowly, probably due to the scaling and size of the resulting image.

**Option 4: Set center behaviour**

Using BorderLayout tried every center behaviour (and no behaviour, just placing it was tried too). Added Image as Label icon.

Result: Image did not scale, plus it appeared on the left side of the screen, not on the center.

Can´t remember if I missed an option, in any case, all options work fine with static images loaded from jpgs or pngs, is Timeline the problem?

Is there someway to actually make an animated splash screen? (I am not against using a video, in that case I would need to make the controls go away and the transition at the end be instantaneous, tried with a timer and the on completion callback, both showed a black rectangle the size of the video before transitioning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a regression there. We'll fix it for the next update.

You don't need to call `requiresDrawImage()` as it's a callback for our usage internally. The 1st method you picked should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Shai, yes I realized the requiresDrawImage() just returns a boolean later that day, I was on  a "lets try anything" frame of mind when I put it in.